# Google Cloud Run billing SKUs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

While using the Billing Reports in the Google Cloud Console, I am trying to filter down the SKUs related to Cloud Run.

What are the SKUs associated with Cloud Run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "Reports" tab of the Billing section , you should be able to select "Cloud Run" in the "Product" filter and then group by "SKU":

[image: Filter and grouping]

When doing so, you will see the list of SKUs that apply to Cloud Run.

I particular:

- Memory Allocation Time
- Requests
- CPU Allocation Time
- and the many network related SKUs

Here is what I see in my project:

[image: Billing SKUs]